# PHP doenst catch a simple POST

Tags: php, html, forms, post, submit

Here below is my code, i get strange results, for example the POST is not being caught by the PHP. If i add `($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')` it is still not caught. It hould be a simple `POST`, what did i do wrong? The best i get out of this is the error message:

> $url_message = 'Something went wro, please try again.';

Please help

```
                    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {  

                            $btc = $_POST['bitcoin'];
                            $eur = $_POST['euro']; 

                            echo '1';
                            echo $btc;
                            echo '2';
                            echo $eur;

                        if($btc != "" && $eur != ""){

                            $user_idr = $_GET['id'];
                            $user_idreal = $LS->get_CU();
                            echo $LS->get_CU();
                            echo $user_idr;


                            if($user_idr == $user_idreal){                          
                                 echo 'jemoder';
                                    $cur = $btc;
                                    $eur = $eur;
                                    $user = $user_id;
                                    $datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                                    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

                                if($LS->store_val($cur, $eur, $user, $datetime, $ip) != false){

                                        $url_message = 'Gelukt';
                                        header('Location: home.php?id=' . $header_n . '&mas=' . $url_message);

                                }else{

                                        $url_message = 'niet gelukt';
                                        header('Location: home.php?id=' . $header_n . '&mas=' . $url_message);

                                }

                            }else{ 

                                $header_n = $LS->get_CU();


                                $url_message = 'Something went wro, please try again.';
                                header('Location: home.php?id=' . $header_n . '&mas=' . $url_message);

                            }

                        }else{

                            $header_n = $LS->get_CU();

                            $url_message = 'Some fields were left blank.';
                            header('Location: home.php?id=' . $header_n . '&mas=' . $url_message);

                        }
                    }else{

                        echo 'hallo';

                    }



                    ?>      

        <div class="col-md-9">  
            <div class="span9">
                <div class="space-6"></div>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span12">
                        <form class="form-horizontal formproperties" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>#form-textfield" method="POST">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row-fluid">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6 logintextsupport text-center">
                                            <h3 class="text-left">Buy <?php echo $form_titel;?></h3>

                                            <hr />

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="col-md-1 control-label" for="password"></label> 

                                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                                    <input id="<?php echo $form_id;?>" name="<?php echo $form_name;?>" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $form_placeholder;?> *" class="form-control input-md" required="">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="col-md-1 control-label" for="password"></label>  
                                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <input id="euro" name="euro" type="text" placeholder=" *" class="form-control input-md" required="">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <legend>Payment Method</legend>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="col-md-1 control-label" for="password"></label>  
                                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                                    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" /> <label for="radio1" class="inline">iDeal</label><br />
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                                    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3" /> <label for="radio3" class="inline">Ban Contact</label>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>

                                            <hr />

                                            <div class="form-group loginboxsupport">
                                                <label class="col-md-12 col-lg-12" for="proceed"></label>
                                                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                                    <button id="proceed" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success buttonali">SUBMIT</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div style="height:0.5vw;"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
```

Comment: First step is to make sure that the request actually _is_ a http post request and that it results in the execution of your script. The next step is to dump the contents of the `$_POST` super global variable.

Comment: Why *<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>* in action of your form ?

Comment: you should remove the action part if you have php code on same page, you # tag stops the submission of page

Comment: i removed the # tag in the action but same results :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the HTML code, at the `action` there is the following code

```
action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>#form-textfield"
```

So the action would be a link to itself, nothing on it. Had to add a user ID:

```
?id=<?php echo $user_id ?>
```

The complete action became:

```
action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>?id=<?php echo $user_id ?>#form-textfield"
```

The total start of the form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal formproperties" action="home.php?id=<?php echo $user_id ?>#form-textfield" method="POST">
```